# How to get QTreeWidgetItem position?

Tags: qt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

How shall I get a *QTreeWidgetItem* LeftTop position (in pixel) after I get this item with the *itemAt*?

Is there a simple way?

Comment: Does the `QTreeWidgetItem` contains a `QWidget`? if so, you can use it to get to position `treeWidget()->itemWidget(poTreeItem,0)->rect().topLeft();`

Comment: No, pure tree. I have tried this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `QTreeWidgetItem *` `pitem` you can use [`QTreeWidget::visualitemRect`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#visualItemRect)...

```
QRect viewport_relative_rect = pitem->treeWidget()->visualItemRect(pitem);
```